# wordpress child theme: how to overwrite template .php files

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a child theme setup in wordpress and the style.css and functions.php in the child theme are working correctly. I now want to overwrite other template .php files with the versions in the child theme. I can't seem to make these files overwrite the parent theme however.

child theme functions.php:

```
<?php
//enqueue styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 'overwrite' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
//overwrite template pages
function overwrite() {
    wp_enqueue_script( get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/structure/hooks.php' );
    wp_enqueue_script( get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/structure/header.php' );
}
```

I have a hooks.php and header.php in /child-theme/inc/structure/

Answer (score 3):

For a child-theme you do not need to enqueue any template (PHP) files, simply add a PHP file to your child-theme with exactly the same name and path as the one you are trying to overwrite in your parent theme and it will naturally replace it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must be doing something silly. pages in the main template directory still work fine but any pages in subfolders dont. I have: "themes/storefront/inc/structure/hooks.php" in my main template, and my child template directory structure is: "themes/storefront-child/inc/structure/hooks.php" but changes to the hooks.php file in the child template are not overwriting the main template.

Comment: For hooks you need to deregister the original hook and add a new one, see [here](http://venutip.com/content/right-way-override-theme-functions) for more details